# AFNetworking AFHTTPClient AFHttpRequestOperation deadlock on POST

Tags: ios, multithreading, deadlock, afnetworking

I have been having a strange issue where a file upload seems to hang up without my app hanging. I'm assuming this is some sort of deadlock inside AFHTTPClient, although it could be my hosting provider (rackspace cloud sites). Here are some hints, please note that this is rare but it seems to occur most when multiple connections are open at one time.

1. It happens on WIFI and on Cell data networks
2. I am utilizing the upload progress block which is showing 100%
3. The network activity spinner is spinning
4. You can let the app sit there forever and nothing seems to happen until you hit "cancel" on the file upload which the app responds to and the upload cancels successfully and calls my completion block. Upon hitting upload again it works immediately using the identical NSData for the file and a new operation.
5. Other connections start / complete while the upload is hanging there on 100%
6. My server log shows no sign of ever receiving a connection during the hang time. and there is no duplicate upload.
7. The upload is kicked off from a background thread but I believe if it were an issue with my code then the upload would never get this far. The last line of code in the thread is the line where I add my newly created upload operation to the AFHTTPClient queue.

Any Ideas?